HRESULT: 0x2 HTTP status: 500 HTTP subStatus: 1002 HTTP reason: Internal Server Error
I am trying to host my NodeJS and React web app on IIS but for the life of me I cant seem to make it work. I've tried every solution I can find online and I still run into this http 200 error.(https://i.sstatic.net/gwYx1isI.png) Also I am trying to host it on a virtual machine I'm not sure if this affects anything. Any advice is appreciated!! This is my web.config file btw (https://i.sstatic.net/t62x5kyf.jpg)
Below is my server.js file running on port 3000
import cors from 'cors';
import express from "express";
import sql from "mssql";
import { PORT } from './config.js';
import inventoryRouter from './routes/inventoryRoute.js';
import transferRouter from './routes/transferRoute.js';
import orderRouter from './routes/orderRoute.js';
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const sqlConfig = {
user: "testuser",
password: '1234',
// server: 'DESKTOP-VN9PRPU\\SQLEXPRESS', // or 'localhost' for a local instance
server: 'YIHANG\\SQLEXPRESS',
// server: 'MDPADMIN\\SQLEXPRESS',
database: 'inventory',
driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
options: {
    // encrypt: false,
    // trustServerCertificate: true,
    trustedConnection: false,
    encrypt: false
}
};

const app = express();

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/dist')));

let pool;

async function connectDB() {
try {
    pool = await new sql.connect(sqlConfig);
    app.listen(PORT, () => { //PORT is 3000
        console.log("app is running le");
    })
    console.log("connected le");
} catch (err) {
    console.error('error is ', err);
}
}

app.use((req, res, next) => {
req.pool = pool;
next();
})


app.use('/inventory', inventoryRouter);
app.use('/transfers', transferRouter);
app.use('/orders', orderRouter);

app.use('/images', express.static('images'))


connectDB();

UPDATE
i have tried the following solutions but all to no avail

downloaded iisnode and rerouter modules
giving IIS_IUSRS, IUSR & my application pool instance full permissions
setting devErrosEnabled and LoggingEnabled in the iisnode web.config to false
moved my app directory directly to C drive



Host them separately if possible. 2) Use HttpPlatformHandler, instead of iisnode, https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/


Please provide the code of the server.js, and how are the environment variable port configured for server listening?

Try to use app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000) instead of app.listen().
When deploying Node.js with IIS on Windows, port conflicts may occur.Use process.env.PORT allow you to dynamically adapt port and ensuring smooth communication without conflicts.
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000) will read the port from the environment variable process.env.PORT.
If it exists and has a valid value, then  app.listen will use this value as the port. In other case, it will use 3000 as the default port number.

yup I've tried this but is still gives the same error. i've also checked in IIS Manager that the site is binded to port 3000.

Does Node.js app work properly locally?  And Check the Event Viewer for any relevant errors or warning messages for your Node.js app or IIS process.
